# Slow response of server

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, mysql, webserver

I have a local development server in the local network. 
There are many instances of magento sites running there.

Developers work a 5-6 different magento's and when there is such use the server responds very very slow and often gives a 503 error- Site Temporarily unavailable.

I am using apache web server with mysql.

The network is good enough to bear the magento requests going through the local network, also the CPU, RAM and resources usage are okay.

I have checked the log files, access logs and so on, but the server is very slow in response. It takes up to 20-30 seconds often to load a magento page.

also, the mysql service takes a long time to restart.

I am using `Ubuntu16` as my server

Answer (score 0):

It could be the MySQL DB that is slow due to misconfiguration.

Try the [MySQLTuner](https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl) to speed it up.